# If the function $f(x)=(x^3)/(e^{x/2})$ and $g(x)$ is the inverse function, how to find derivative of $g(x)$ at $x=1$?

Tags: calculus

If the function $f(x)=(x^3)/(e^{x/2})$ and g(x) is the inverse function, how to find derivative of g(x) at x=1 ?

Im finding it really difficult to find g(x).Help please! And is there any indirect way to find derivative of g(x) without finding g(x)?

Comment: $g(f(x))=x$ , that would be.

Comment: Read through https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f \prime(f ^{-1}(x))}$$ Where $f^{-1}(x) = g(x)$

Comment: If you knew how to solve f(a) =1, you could find the reciprocal of f'(a) to find g'(1).

Comment: The function f is not one-to-one, as a graph shows; hence, f does not have an inverse. Is there a domain restriction? Should you assume one?

Comment: Moreover, you'd need this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @Mann Why should the Lambert W function be involved here?

Comment: To find $g'(f(x)) \times f'(x)=1$ , at $f(x)=1$ , need a value of $x$. , if the inverse exist over a specified domain. At $x=-6W(\frac{-1}{6})$ , i think.

Comment: @AnuragA so the answer comes around 1/2 ?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta though a rough calculation, might be wrong. The answer seems close to $g'(1)=-2\frac{W(-1/6)}{1+W(-1/6)}$

Comment: @SanchayanDutta , it's the correct answer check.http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2%281-1%2F%281%2BW%28-1%2F6%29%29%29 
Should I write the answer?

Comment: Yeah sure @Mann

Comment: It will take some time, I am working , please wait. Unless, someone answers already. Not a problem. @SanchayanDutta

Comment: @SanchayanDutta , there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $\forall x\in  (R\equiv (-\infty,6]) \; \exists \;f(x)\in D$ , where $R$ is domain of the function, $D$ is the range of function.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/13qav60399

As from the graph of the function, it is clear that it is one-one and onto on it's range and domain.

Now there exists a function $g(y): y \in D \to x \in R $ i.e., $\forall y \in D\; \exists \;x \in R$, Such that $g(y)$ is inverse of $f(x)$.

Then $\exists \;\;$$g(f(x))=x$ which is an identity in $x \in R$. Intuitively, this function takes an $x\in R$ send it to a $f(x)\in D$ and then the function $g(y)$ takes an $f(x)\in D$ and sends it back to $x \in R$.

Now that we have proved the existence of inverse and found the identity function in x,  it's time to use chain rule to differentiate.

---

$$g'(\color{red}{f(x)})\times f'(\color{blue}{x})=1$$

$$\implies g'(\color{red}{f(x)})=\frac{1}{f'(\color{blue}{x})}$$

First let us find what is $\large{\frac{1}{f'(x)}}$, given $f(x)=\large{\frac{x^3}{e^{x/2}}}$

$$f'(x)=\frac{e^{x/2}\times 3x^2-\frac{1}{2}x^3\times e^{x/2}}{e^x}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{6x^3-x^2}{2e^{x/2}}$$

$$\frac{1}{f'(\color{blue}{x})}=\frac{2\color{green}{e^{x/2}}}{\color{brown}{6x^2-x^3}}=g'(\color{red}{f(x)})$$

Now our only problem is to find an $x$ such that $\color{red}{f(x)}=1$ i.e., $\color{blue}{x}^3=e^{\color{blue}{x}/2}$

---

> Here I am going to roughly introduce Lambert W function. 
>   Consider a equation $Xe^{X}=Y$ then it can be written in terms of W function as $X=W(Y)$

Now in our equation, taking cube root both side.

$$\color{blue}{x}=e^{\color{blue}{x}/6}$$

Which can be rewritten as,

$$\color{blue}{x}e^{-\color{blue}{x}/6}=1$$

Substitute $-\frac{\color{blue}{x}}{6}=t$ so that $\color{blue}{x}=-6t$.

$$-6te^t=1$$

$$te^t=\frac{-1}{6}$$

Solution to this is W function given by ,

$$t=W(-\frac{1}{6})$$ and now substituting into $\color{blue}{x}$,

$$\color{blue}{x}=-6W(-\frac{1}{6})$$

---

Now , we will find some coloured terms individually in our derivative expression of $g'(\color{red}{f(x)})$, now that we have a value of $\color{blue}{x}$.

First of all what is, $$\color{green}{e^{x/2}}=e^{-3W(-1/6)}$$

> Here we will use an identity, $$e^{n.W(x)}=\left(\frac{x}{W(x)}\right)^n$$ *shorthand notation $(W(x))^3=W^{3}(x)$*

$$e^{-3W\left(-\frac16\right)}=\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{6}}{W\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)}\right)^{-3}=-216W^{3}\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)$$

---

Secondly what is $ \color{brown}{6x^2-x^3}$

This is pretty straightforward, $$\color{brown}{6x^2-x^3}=216W^2(-\frac16)+216W^3(-\frac16)$$

---

Putting it all together,

$$g'(\color{red}{1})=2\times \frac{\color{green}{-216W^3\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)}}{\color{brown}{216W^2\left(-\frac16\right)+216W^3\left(-\frac16\right)}}$$

Which finally gives us,

$$\bbox[black]{\color{white}{g'(1)=-2 \times \frac{W\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)}{1+W\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)}\approx 0.514083..}}$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2%281-1%2F%281%2BW%28-1%2F6%29%29%29

*PS, I know that the black box looks ugly, but i have always wanted to use that. :)*

Comment: Brilliantly written answer! :-)

Comment: Haha, yes took me about half an hour , not so good with mathax, indeed. So is this answer ok? @SanchayanDutta and you may like to join here, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23760/we-love-math-physics-chemistry-and-random-talk. It's a small though inactive at moment group including people from india.Mostly +2 passouts, like me.

Answer (score 0):

When it exists (that is, when there *is* an inverse function), if you set $y=g(x)$, the general formula is:
$$g'(x)=\frac1{f'(y)}$$
provided $f'(y)\neq 0$. If $f'(y_0)=0$, $g$ is not differentiable at $x_0$.

The main problem consists in expressing the result as an explicit function of $x$. This cannot always be realised.

Comment: So the answer comes to be something around 1/2 ?

Comment: I don't get you. The result, for a general $x$, depends on $x$.

Comment: I said at x=1.Look at the question!

Comment: Sorry! I did not solve for $f(y)=1$. However, we know this means $y^3=\mathrm e^{\tfrac y2}$ so that for such a $y$, we have $g'(x)=\dfrac{2y}{3-y}$. Is this compatible with what you've found?

Comment: yes roughly :-)

Comment: I've found a derivative  $\approx 1.384$.